# how to format array of arrays using lodash

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I am using lodash to group a array by a property "isRouteId" which looks like this:

```
    [
    [
        {
            "key": 0,
            "isSurveyId": null,
            "isPausedId": null,
            "isRouteId": "7778a8b2-2a92-49f3-b910-089231678412",
            "isPaused": false,
            "subdivisionId": 0,
            "latlngObj": {
                "latitude": 29.5407882,
                "longitude": -95.7732222
            }
        },
        {
            "key": 1,
            "isSurveyId": null,
            "isPausedId": null,
            "isRouteId": "7778a8b2-2a92-49f3-b910-089231678412",
            "isPaused": false,
            "subdivisionId": 0,
            "latlngObj": {
                "latitude": 29.5406792,
                "longitude": -95.7732779
            }
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "key": 71,
            "isSurveyId": null,
            "isPausedId": null,
            "isRouteId": "ddb42ef3-6c0e-48fc-9bcb-0a64ad422db4",
            "isPaused": false,
            "subdivisionId": 0,
            "latlngObj": {
                "latitude": 29.5332458,
                "longitude": -95.7766514
            }
        },
        {
            "key": 72,
            "isSurveyId": null,
            "isPausedId": null,
            "isRouteId": "ddb42ef3-6c0e-48fc-9bcb-0a64ad422db4",
            "isPaused": false,
            "subdivisionId": 0,
            "latlngObj": {
                "latitude": 29.5331976,
                "longitude": -95.7765264
            }
        },
        {
            "key": 73,
            "isSurveyId": null,
            "isPausedId": null,
            "isRouteId": "ddb42ef3-6c0e-48fc-9bcb-0a64ad422db4",
            "isPaused": false,
            "subdivisionId": 0,
            "latlngObj": {
                "latitude": 29.5331486,
                "longitude": -95.7763998
            }
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "key": 93,
            "isSurveyId": null,
            "isPausedId": null,
            "isRouteId": "7a343973-95b4-4508-9076-15a6ebae5555",
            "isPaused": false,
            "subdivisionId": 0,
            "latlngObj": {
                "latitude": 29.5321796,
                "longitude": -95.7738858
            }
        },
        {
            "key": 94,
            "isSurveyId": null,
            "isPausedId": null,
            "isRouteId": "7a343973-95b4-4508-9076-15a6ebae5555",
            "isPaused": false,
            "subdivisionId": 0,
            "latlngObj": {
                "latitude": 29.5321292,
                "longitude": -95.7737588
            }
        }
    ]
]
```

I need help with the next step which is to take the nested "latlngObj" properties and move them to the root level. 
Which the Desired Result needs to look like this:

```
    [
    [
        {
            "key": 0,
            "isSurveyId": null,
            "isPausedId": null,
            "isRouteId": "7778a8b2-2a92-49f3-b910-089231678412",
            "isPaused": false,
            "subdivisionId": 0,
            "latitude": 29.5407882,
             "longitude": -95.7732222
        },
        {
            "key": 1,
            "isSurveyId": null,
            "isPausedId": null,
            "isRouteId": "7778a8b2-2a92-49f3-b910-089231678412",
            "isPaused": false,
            "subdivisionId": 0,
            "latitude": 29.5406792,
            "longitude": -95.7732779
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "key": 71,
            "isSurveyId": null,
            "isPausedId": null,
            "isRouteId": "ddb42ef3-6c0e-48fc-9bcb-0a64ad422db4",
            "isPaused": false,
            "subdivisionId": 0,
            "latitude": 29.5332458,
            "longitude": -95.7766514
        },
        {
            "key": 72,
            "isSurveyId": null,
            "isPausedId": null,
            "isRouteId": "ddb42ef3-6c0e-48fc-9bcb-0a64ad422db4",
            "isPaused": false,
            "subdivisionId": 0,
            "latitude": 29.5331976,
            "longitude": -95.7765264
        },
        {
            "key": 73,
            "isSurveyId": null,
            "isPausedId": null,
            "isRouteId": "ddb42ef3-6c0e-48fc-9bcb-0a64ad422db4",
            "isPaused": false,
            "subdivisionId": 0,
            "latitude": 29.5331486,
            "longitude": -95.7763998
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "key": 93,
            "isSurveyId": null,
            "isPausedId": null,
            "isRouteId": "7a343973-95b4-4508-9076-15a6ebae5555",
            "isPaused": false,
            "subdivisionId": 0,
            "latitude": 29.5321796,
             "longitude": -95.7738858
        },
        {
            "key": 94,
            "isSurveyId": null,
            "isPausedId": null,
            "isRouteId": "7a343973-95b4-4508-9076-15a6ebae5555",
            "isPaused": false,
            "subdivisionId": 0,
            "latitude": 29.5321292,
            "longitude": -95.7737588
        }
    ]
]
```

I know how to do it using jquery but that is not available. I need to use lodash, underscore or javascript to achieve this.

[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/kibkrPHi8i3zGz4ps3An?p=preview)

```
  var result = _(routesById).groupBy('isRouteId').values().value();

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 _.each(result,(model) => {
   _.each(model,(_model) => {
     _model.latitude = _model.latlngObj.latitude;
     _model.longitude = _model.latlngObj.longitude;
     delete _model.latlngObj;
   });
});
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/D1hnaRGZNY8TC1pAARJj?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

I would take the following approach:

```
_(coll)
  .flatten()
  .map(i => _.assign({}, _.omit(i, 'latlngObj'), i.latlngObj))
  .groupBy('isRouteId')
  .value()
```

The first step is to [flatten()](https://lodash.com/docs#flatten) the array, so then you can just [map()](https://lodash.com/docs#map) the items. The idea is that the map iteratee uses [assign()](https://lodash.com/docs#assign) to add the `latlngObj` properties, while [omit()](https://lodash.com/docs#omit) is used to get rid of `latlngObj` since it is no longer needed (you can skip the `omit()` part if you want).

Then it's a simple call to [groupBy()](https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy) to finish off the chain.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that only requires one iteration over your collection.  We do all the work inside the `groupBy` iterating function before returning the groupBy key.

```
var result = _(routesById).groupBy(function(model) {
  model.latitude = model.latlngObj.latitude;
  model.longitude = model.latlngObj.longitude;
  delete(model.latlngObj);
  return model.isRouteId;
}).values().value();
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/DORid3q9jEzaFlVsN581?p=preview)